# What is the correct way to insert the end of the enema tube?

Tags: digestion

I have been trying enema for a couple of days. When I insert the rectal strip, it goes about a inch in. But when I release the water, nothing happens. I don't see the water flowing into me.

My suspicion is that I may not be inserting the strip correctly. How can I make sure that the end of the tube has really reached into the colon?

How can the tube pass the anal sphincter and reach into the colon?

Comment: If the water doesn't go into you, where does it go?

Comment: It goes nowhere. It does not flow at all. It is as if the end of the tube is against an obstacle.

Comment: Have you tried letting the water flow a bit first? A big air bubble can make it harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're doing enemas because a doctor ordered it. If not, then I recommend you just don't do it at all. Enemas are not harmless and unless there's constipation they have no benefits. And even then they shouldn't be used routinely. There are safer, healthier ways to manage constipation.

I'll also assume you're sure you're using the device correctly, that it doesn't have some sort of valve that is blocking flow.

That said, it sounds like you're simply not inserting it far enough. The tip needs to go 2-3 inches into the rectum to get past the anal sphincter. One inch isn't enough. You need to use some lubricant on the tip, preferably something water-based. Your local pharmacy should have a number of choices. But in a pinch you can use stuff like Vaseline, or even a plain vegetable oil such as olive oil.

Although this article is written as instructions for nurses giving enemas to patients, it covers things you need to know about enemas.

https://www.nursingtimes.net/clinical-archive/gastroenterology/how-to-administer-an-enema/203226.article